# What makes a webpage dynamic?

Tags: html, dynamic, static

I just want to know how much dynamic pages a site contains, so how can identify the dynamic pages in it, does the presence of a form makes a page dynamic ?

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: This makes no sense in its current form. What do you mean by "dynamic" exactly?

Comment: Suppose I want to find the number of dynamic webpages in stackoverflow.com, how do I identify those pages ?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"? It's a word that can mean several different things.

Comment: Dynamic pages are those webpages whose content changes, unlike the static page whose content change only when the website developer edits its content and publishes it .

Comment: There is no way to find out which pages are "dynamic" in that way and which are not - they all look the same to the outside. On a site like Stack Overflow, you can safely assume that almost all pages are "dynamic" in that nothing is hard coded into the HTML. What is your real-world use case, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Dynamic in this context usually means that it changes in reaction to data changes without user intervention.  Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A webpage is considered dynamic if the html, JavaScript, etc. is generated by a script or program and not written by hand, i.e. not static.  If the script/program responds to parameters, database data, or any kind of variable data to generate it's content, then it is considered dynamic.  i.e. the when data/variables change then the webpage changes.

Comment: Thanks for the down-vote! It would be nice to see a comment explaining why my answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "dynamic" I guess you mean populated server-side using a language such as php/c#.

Not all dynamic pages have a form, for example CMS pages are just displaying content to end-users.
You cannot do this accurately because some pages are restricted and for some others you cannot know if that has been generated, but an idea is to check at pages in the sitemap (if any) of the website.

I guess all pages are dynamic in StackOverflow, on pages like "About" I guess they can edit the content in the backend.
Moreover in StackOverflow the banner is dynamic (so all pages using this banner) because of your username/notifications.

Personally none of my websites contain a static page.